# Struggling to retrieve the url for connected accounts in Stripe from server PHP file

Tags: php, swiftui, uikit, stripe-payments

I am working with this documentation to incorporate Connected Stripe Accounts in my iOS Application. When we call the  “OURFILE.PHP” file, it outputs “url” within the output JSON data. We are trying to use this url and set it to “accountURL” and open in Safari.

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

let BackendAPIBaseURL: String = “OURFILE.PHP”

class ConnectOnboardViewController: UIViewController {

    // ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let connectWithStripeButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        connectWithStripeButton.setTitle("Connect with Stripe", for: .normal)
        connectWithStripeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didSelectConnectWithStripe), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(connectWithStripeButton)

        // ...
    }

    @objc
    func didSelectConnectWithStripe() {
        if let url = URL(string: BackendAPIBaseURL)?.appendingPathComponent("onboard-user") {
          print(url)
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
          request.httpMethod = "POST"
            print("hi0")
          let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
              guard let data = data,
                  let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any],
                  let accountURLString = json["url"] as? String,
                  let accountURL = URL(string: accountURLString)
              else {
                      // handle error
                  print("hi")
                  print(error)
                  print(response)
                  print(data)
                  
                  return
                  
              }

              let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: accountURL)
              safariViewController.delegate = self

              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.present(safariViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
              }
          }
        }
    }

    // ...
}

extension ConnectOnboardViewController: SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
    func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) {
        // the user may have closed the SFSafariViewController instance before a redirect
        // occurred. Sync with your backend to confirm the correct state
    }
}
```

However, it seems like the code is skipping this block

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
              guard let data = data,
                  let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any],
                  let accountURLString = json["url"] as? String,
                  let accountURL = URL(string: accountURLString)
              else {
                      // handle error
                  print("hi")
                  print(error)
                  print(response)
                  print(data)
                  
                  return
                  
              }
```

We have this button in a different view:

```
Button {
                            self.isLoading = true
                            ConnectOnboardViewController().didSelectConnectWithStripe()
                            self.isLoading = false
                    }
```

We’ve been working on this for a few hours trying to debug and was wondering if anyone has encountered this same issue as well?

Comment: have you tried using `task.resume()` after you declare your `task`?

Comment: Was `didSelectConnectWithStripe` ever called?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Thanks for the help! The task.resume() actually fixed this issue after I reconfigured the json data (I had formatted it improperly in the link).

However, now we get an error saying: "[Presentation] Attempt to present <...> on <...> (from <...>) whose view is not in the window heirarchy". Working on debugging now, but do you happen to know what might be causing this?

Comment: Without some reasonable amount of code, such as, what is [Presentation] etc... it is not possible for me to debug. Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Show the full error messages you get and on which line of the code. Show some minimalist code we can compile and run.